# Word Styles duplicate

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

When I make a change to one of my own styles in Word, Word automatically create a new style with the same name but adds the change next to the style. How do I disable this feature? I had a look and played around in Autocorrect but no luck. I know this could be disabled in previous versions of Word. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but if you are seeing these in the full Styles dialog, and they do not have an icon at the right indicating the style type, then they are not actually styles. You can probably remove them from the list using the Options button in that dialog box, then uncheck Font Formatting.